# Differ Dropdown From manually Selected and auto-Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I have the following logic question. I have 3 cascading dropdowns, ddl1, ddl2, ddl3, which call their functions on change events respectively.

When I select ddl1 manually, it sets ddl2, ddl3 and calls ddl1, dd2, dd3 functions on change event.

When I select ddl2 manually it sets ddl3, ddl Automatically and calls dd2,dd3 functions on change events.

Can I use some kind of logic to differentiate that ddl2 was selected manually? Or it is auto selected due to autochange event of ddl1?

I am not able to find answer for this kind of logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a flag to check this.

Set a `flag = false` initially. On setting ddl1 set `flag = true` .

Now ddl2 change event you can check the value of the flag , if it's false it has been selected manually , else by ddl1.

You might need to use multiple flags to do the same for all drop downs.

Do not know if this is the most efficient way , but it can certainly work.

Here is a pseudo code

```
 flag= false
  ddl1click()
     {
      flag = true
      do something
      }
  ddl2change()
     {
      if(flag)
         do things when triggered by ddl1
         flag = false
      else
        do things when in case of manual selection
      }
```

Comment: I Tried to make it By Flag , but it was not working for multiple dropdowns

Comment: It must be possible. Please share some code so that it can be analysed further. You will need to use multiple flags.

Comment: ok , I tried to make it with 3 dropdowns , flag was working for 2 dropdowns , but failed for greater then 2 dropdown and flag , will get back to you with some code samples